# Separate text in string

Tags: php

I'm getting this result from my mysql database:

```
$_SESSION['svrdata'] = 
 187.14.12.48:admin:root:/home/svr/,
 187.14.12.72:admin:root:/home/svr2/, 
 187.14.12.2:admin:root:/home/svr3/

187.14.12.x = IP
admin = login
root = password
/home/svr/ = directory
```

How to put only these IP address in dropdown menu?

```
$myString = $_SESSION['svrdata']; //
$myArray = explode(',', $myString);
echo '<select multiple="multiple" name="field[]" id="field[]"">';
echo '<option selected="true" value="0" disabled>Select</option>';

$string = explode(':', $myArray);
foreach ($string as $line) {
echo '<option value='.$line.'>'.$line.'</option>';
}
echo '</select>';
```

Have no errors, but still showing nothing. How can I solve it?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

you can use explode  http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

```
$str = '187.14.12.48:admin:root:/home/svr/'; 
$string = explode(':', $str);

print_r($string);
```

**UPDATED:**

```
$myString = ' 187.14.12.48:admin:root:/home/svr/, 187.14.12.72:admin:root:/home/svr2/,  187.14.12.2:admin:root:/home/svr3/'; 
$ipAddress = [];
$myArray = explode(',', $myString);
foreach ($myArray as $array) {
    $tempArray = explode(':', $array);
    $ipAddress[] =  $tempArray[0];
}
echo '<select multiple="multiple" name="field[]" id="field[]"">';
echo '<option selected="true" value="0" disabled>Select</option>';

$string = explode(':', $myArray);
foreach ($ipAddress as $line) {
echo '<option value='.$line.'>'.$line.'</option>';
}
echo '</select>';
```

**EXPLANATION:**
Loop through your `$myArray` and then explode `:`  assign into new array which is called `$ipAddress` so it will contain only ip addresses.

Comment: Thanks! it helped me a lot, now I have updated the thread to get more informations.